# Using template type with default type without angle brackets

Tags: c++

I was playing with this example code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 6);
 
    for (int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        //Use `distrib` to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into an int in [1, 6]
        std::cout << distrib(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

... and noticed that the following two ways both work:

```cpp
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 6);
std::uniform_int_distribution distrib(1, 6);
```

However, there isn't a non-template `std::uniform_int_distribution`, so I assume the second one is equivalent to the first one. What is this feature (being able to omit angle brackets) called and in what version of C++ was this introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this feature (being able to omit angle brackets) called and in what version of C++ was this introduced?

This (somewhat controversial) feature is called class template argument deduction (short: CTAD) and has been introduced with C++17. You can read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction). If you compile this snippet with e.g. `-std=c++14`, it won't compile.

Comment: `somewhat controversial`
Citation needed.

Comment: @lisyarus [Here](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/09/wctad/) you go, and [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2018/12/09/deducing-your-intentions/).